# how to know which excel sheet is empty using oledb c#?

Tags: c#, oledb

I'm getting excel sheet name but just the sheet that has data.

```
String fpath = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source=" +tbpath.Text+ ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';";
file = new OleDbConnection(fpath);
file.Open();
dt = file.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

if (dt == null)
{
    //return null;
}
cbsheet.Enabled = true;
//String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
//int i = 0;

// Add the sheet name to the string array.
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    if (row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("$") )//checks whether row contains '_xlnm#_FilterDatabase' or sheet name(i.e. sheet name always ends with $ sign)
    {
        cbsheet.Items.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
    }
}

//return excelSheets;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR: "+ex);
}
```

Comment: I replicated your code. I was getting only the sheet with data. I renamed a second sheet, now I am getting that one even though it contains no data

Comment: I just need sheet with data.

Comment: Do you need the data in the sheet or the sheet name as you code suggests?

Comment: I need the sheet name if the sheet has data, in my code i get all the sheet name evenif  the sheet is empty.

Comment: DO the empty sheets need to be there? Can you not delete them if they are empty?

Comment: I don't need the empty sheets, but i don't know how to delete from my query

Answer (score 0):

You could check each sheet for rows i.e.

```
try 
{
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("$") )
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(
              "select * from [" + row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "]", file);

            using (DbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    cbsheet.Items.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
                }
                dr.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR: "+ex);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, always show me all the sheet also empty sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can just exclude them from getting added.

I used this code to filter out empty sheets. Turns out
they are sheets that shouldn't be accessed by the user.

You can solve this problem in 2 ways.

a. Ignore them

b. Drop down the sheets.

I would highly suggest going with the former.

Use this code;

```
if (!dt.Rows[i]["Table_Name"].ToString().Contains("FilterDatabase") && !dt.Rows[i]["Table_Name"].ToString().EndsWith("$'"))
{
}
```